# How to access OLD/NEW vaules in a trigger dynamically?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-12

I have a code in the DB trigger like

```
_association_id bigint;
if TG_OP = 'INSERT' then
     select concat('NEW.',association_field_id) INTO _association_id from association_audit_configs where table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME;
elsif TG_OP = 'DELETE' then
     select  concat('OLD.',association_field_id) INTO _association_id from association_audit_configs where table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME;
end if;
```

I have columns names in association_field_id column of association_audit_configs table. Example: If I have the value as computer_id in association_field_id, I want to assign the value of OLD.computer_id to _association_id. But its considering as "OLD.computer_id" eventually getting error as input syntax for type bigint: "OLD.computer_id". How can I make it to consider as OLD.computer_id while assigning to _association_id ?

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: @jjanes Thanks. I've been trying to use dynamic SQL but I'm not able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

cast the records to hstore.

```
if TG_OP = 'INSERT' then
     select hstore(NEW)->association_field_id INTO _association_id from association_audit_configs where table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME;
elsif TG_OP = 'DELETE' then
     select  hstore(OLD)->association_field_id INTO _association_id from association_audit_configs where table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME;
end if;
```